# How to open different view controllers when a collectionView cell is click

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I'm wondering how to open different viewControllers when a specific cell is click in my collectionView. For this example lets say I have a collectionView that looks like this.

[image]

Pretend there is no label just a colored view. Now let say I have 3 different viewControllers in my storyboard for each collectionView cell. Storyboard looks like this.

[image]

This is where I find myself stuck. So when the the orange cell is click I would like to show the viewController that is orange and vise versa with the other cells. I know how to show one viewController for all the cells but not different viewControllers for specific cells. So how would I be able to achieve this. Would really appreciate any help or links. Thanks for taking the time to read my question. :)

Comment: With collectionViewCell you are showing image or simply label and view With background Color?

Comment: For this simple example just the background color and when the color is click I want it to display the viewController with the same color. However, I was able to achieve by using the second answer by Shabir. Using the cell background color. The first answer didn't know how to add different identifiers. So how would I add different Identifiers?

Comment: For that you need to register cell with different reuse identifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do that by accessing the color property of cell background.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    if (cell?.backgroundColor == .red) {
        // go to red
    }
    else if (cell?.backgroundColor == .orange) {
        // go to orange
    }

}
```

Comment: Shabir thanks for taking the time to reply to my question. Would I need to drag another collectionViewCell into the collectionView for every color? Cause as you see in the storyboard screen shot it only has one cell. So would I need to add more cells into the collectionView.

Comment: Thanks Shabir, was finally able to achieve the behavior I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to different identifier to cell for identify your clicked cell . OR you can do using cell's color string

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    if (cell?.reuseIdentifier == "red") {
        // go to red
    }
    else if (cell?.reuseIdentifier == "orage") {
        // go to orange
    }

}
```

Comment: KKRocks thanks for taking the time to reply to my question. Would I need to drag another collectionViewCell into the collectionView for every color? Cause as you see in the storyboard screen shot it only has one cell. So would I need to add more cells into the collectionView.

Comment: Never mind figured it out. Was finally able to achieve the behavior that I wanted using Shabir method. I didn't fully understand your method. How would I be able to add a reusable Identifier to the others cells besides the prototype cell in the storyboard